# Validating APK for Nokia X has issues. Error 305 - The APK file contains an invalid certificate

Tags: nokiax

I already have an App Enpass password manager for Nokia X which was submitted on Feb 25 2014. Today I am trying to update it but I am not able to validate the content file. On clicking the validate button I get following msg

305 - The APK file contains an invalid certificate. It is either CN (common name) = Android Debug or the certificate expires before Oct 22, 2033.

I have double checked everything and found my certificate expired in 2041 and CN is our company name. I am sure that this is not my fault as when I try to validate the old file (Which is live on Store now) its also get rejection with same error msg.

Please assist so that I can publish a new update ASAP.

Comment: I would delete the APK file, do cleanup for the project and then try re-creating the file with new certificate.

Comment: Please double check that your certificates subject field contains non-empty CN-element.

Comment: I was just testing apk update and it worked with my certificate & apk.